# Non-Touch ID Mac says "Touch ID requires password when Mac restarts"

Tags: mac, touch-id

I used Carbon Copy Cloner to move from one MacBook Pro to another and have found that while the newer Mac does not have the fingerprint sensor, the OS still reports "Touch ID requires password when Mac restarts".

Does anyone know how to clear this setting on my Non-Touch ID Mac?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the OS still probably thinks you're using a MacBook Pro with a fingerprint scanner. If you still have both MacBooks, a possible solution is to go back to the other MacBook Pro and disable the TouchID settings and then use Carbon Copy Cloner to move from the old MacBook Pro to the new MacBook Pro.

Comment: Yes- I'm aware of why this is happening at a high level, but I need to know what the exact mechanism is for controlling these settings.  I no longer have access to the old MacBook.